# How to get resolution for dual monitor in Java

Tags: java, resolution

In the case of a single monitor using java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

but In dual monitor what should I do now?

Comment: I believe you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6322681/1175077

Answer (score 2):

What you want is:

```
GraphicsDevice[] monitors = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
```

Which will be a list of all the monitors attached to the system.

Those GraphicsDevice objects have a suite of useful methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For using your sentence, I only figured out the fact I'm using dual monitors. But what I really want to know is how can I figure out resolution of each monitors (ex) resolution of graphicsdevice[0] and graphicsdevice[1]). I'm waiting your answer!

Comment: graphicsdevice[0].getDisplayMode().getWidth() and .getHeight()