# Fullscreen Exclusive mode JDesktopPane

Tags: java, desktop-application, mdi, touchscreen, jdesktoppane

Is it a bad idea to make a full-screen mdi application? Has anyone else ever tried this? Currently working on redesigning an application that is used on touchscreen terminals. Space is critical and I believe that being able to maximize, resize, etc application windows would really make the terminals more robust. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Edit: Made a simple app and it doesn't seem to have any issues. Concerned about possible future issues though.

Edit:
[JDialog Not Displaying When in Fullscreen Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722922/jdialog-not-displaying-when-in-fullscreen-mode)
Issues with dialogs must make it difficult for confirmation boxes.

Edit: JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog works great for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have researched for the last few days and there seems to not be any formally documented issues with running a fullscreen mdi application written in java.